# trying to pull filename from array and INSERT into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, upload

i have coded some file upload php code which uploads multiple files, renames them in a loop and submits data on a form.

im now trying to pull the uploaded filenames and INSERT them into database, but at moment struggling to even echo them upon form complete.

can anyone help me get the new filenames and help me with getting the data into my database?

here is some of my code;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

// Variables for date&Time logs
$dateLog = date("y-m-d"); // DATE OF  ADDITION
$timeLog = date("H:i:s", time() - 3600);   // TIME OF ADDITION 

// INSERT QUERY
$sql="INSERT INTO $table1 (firstname, lastname, companyname, phone, email, name, make, serial, catagory, price, location, description, sold, operational, year, clear, rip, version, service, dock, loading, available, extras, dateadded, featured)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]',
'$_POST[lastname]',
'$_POST[companyname]',
'$_POST[phone]',
'$_POST[email]',
'$_POST[name]',
'$_POST[make]',
'$_POST[serial]',
'$_POST[catagory]',
'$_POST[price]',
'$_POST[location]',
'$_POST[description]',
'No',
'$_POST[operational]',
'$_POST[year]',
'$_POST[clear]',
'$_POST[rip]',
'$_POST[version]',
'$_POST[service]',
'$_POST[dock]',
'$_POST[loading]',
'$_POST[available]',
'$_POST[extras]',
'$dateLog',
'No')";


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot query the database.<br>" . mysql_error());

// start of image upload
$insert_id = mysql_insert_id() or die("Unable to get insert id for image name.<br>" . mysql_error());

extract($_POST);
    $error=array();
    $extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
    foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
            {
                $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
                $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(in_array($ext,$extension))
                {
                    if(!file_exists("../images/listings/".$file_name))
                    {
                        $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                        $newFileName=$insert_id."_".mt_rand(1, 99999).".".$ext;
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"../images/listings/".$newFileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                        $newFileName=$filename.mt_rand(1, 99999).".".$ext;
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"../images/listings/".$newFileName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    array_push($error,"$file_name, ");
                }
            }
// end of image upload
//echo '<p>This item was added successfully</p>';
  print_r($newFileName);

}
?>
```

and my form items;

```
1: Upload : <input type="file" name="files[]"/><br />
2: Upload : <input type="file" name="files[]"/><br />
3: Upload : <input type="file" name="files[]"/><br />
4: Upload : <input type="file" name="files[]"/><br />
```

Cheers

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: i'm currently trying to change all my obsolete code to PDO, but this occasion the coding is stored on a local server and hopefully away from public use. ;)

Comment: "Hopefully" is the word here, because this is radioactive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php string and array, use {$_POST['field']}..

Try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $table1 (firstname, lastname, companyname, phone, email, name, make, serial, catagory, price, location, description, sold, operational, year, clear, rip, version, service, dock, loading, available, extras, dateadded, featured)
VALUES
('{$_POST['firstname']}',
'{$_POST['lastname']}'
.... continue
```

And, check if isset($_POST['field']) is a good idea.